# How is membership testing different for a list and a set?

Tags: python, list, set, member

I'm having trouble with figuring out why the first of these assertions is OK and the second raises an error.

```
subject_list = [Subject("A"), Subject("B"), Subject("C")]
subject_set = set()
subject_set.add(Subject("A"))
subject_set.add(Subject("B"))
subject_set.add(Subject("C"))

self.assertIn(Subject("A"), subject_list)
self.assertIn(Subject("A"), subject_set)
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\testSubject.py", line 34, in testIn
    self.assertIn(Subject("A"), subject_set)
AssertionError: <Subject: A> not found in set([<Subject: B>, <Subject: C>, <Subject: A>])
```

The test for equality in the Subject class is simply `self.name == other.name`, and in another UnitTest I verify that `Subject("A") == Subject("A")` . I really can't figure out why the subject is in the list and not in the set. Ideally I'd like the subject to be in both.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The expression

```
Subject("A") in subject_list
```

will compare `Subject("A")` to each entry in `subject_list` using the `Subject.__eq__()` method.  If this method is not overwritten, it defaults to always return `False` unless the two operands are the *same object*.  The above expression would always return `False` if `Subject` lacked a `__eq__()` method, since `Subject("A")` is a new instance which cannot already be in the list.

The expression

```
Subject("A") in subject_set
```

on the contrary will use `Subject.__hash__()` first to find the right bucket, and use `Subject.__eq__()` only after this.  If you did not define `Subject.__hash__()` in a way compatible with `Subject.__eq__()`, this will fail.

Comment: Thanks!  Implementing a __hash__() function in the Subject class solved this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Membership in a set also depends on the object's hash, and as such you must implement the `__hash__()` method on the class appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

Either you don't have a `__hash__()` method in your `Subject` class, or it is dodgy. Try this:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.name)
```

The docs are [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__).

Answer (score 2):

To use these in a set, you have to make sure `Subject` is properly hashable. If you do not define `__hash__` yourself, it will simply take the `id`, and that is different for different instances. `__hash__` should be defined such that equal objects have equal hashes.